Is there a nice name for this "$L$" function that shows up in the Euler-Lagrange Equations?
I've been reading through another part of Arnol'ds book, and we tend to be finding extremals of a functional $\omega$ which has as domain the space of compactly supported curves in $\mathbb R^n$, and as range the real number line. More precisely, we find extremals for
$$ \omega (y) = \int \limits_{\text{dom } y} L(x, y(x), \dot y(x)) \,dx$$
I was wondering if there's a common name for this $L$ function, be it
"Lagrange function" or "length function" or whatnot. Is there a common term for it?

I think its usually called the Lagrangian.
